# Joomla custom PHP code ( post action ) request submit result

Tags: php, joomla

i am again stuck in joomla doing as usual an unusual task so please help.

i am using joomla Joomla! 3.4.8 and i created custom PHP search box (search.php) and its result page (results.php) which shows result from database what ever request submitted from search box fields it get results from DB and showing to me.

Ok after testing PHP search page to another PHP result page and confirming everything is perfect i placed search page code in joomla custom-html module by using nonumber extension it shows results fine on my result page which URL is described in a custom PHP page (results.php) so everything seems fine till this point.

Now when i placed results.php page code very carefully in my joomla article by using same extension nonumber-sourcerer and updated new URL e.g (myjoomla.com/my-results) in the URL inside search page code so when i search my browser take me to my mentioned/given URL BUT shows no record :( even same results.php code is inside !

my post action is following: `<form name="search-fare-plan" method="post" action="results.php">`

and when i call a joomla page code it is like: `<form name="search-fare-plan" method="post" action="my-results">`

Any help would be much appreciated please...

Comment: Dear Heros, i was expecting i simple code hint or possible code example to move on :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://www.nonumber.nl/forum/sourcerer/1096-form-submission-within-source):

> Indeed, has nothing to do with Sourcerer, but with custom (php) coding in Joomla.
>   Check the php code of other forms in Joomla, like the login module or some component that as a form. 
> Basically your form should post to the main index.php and post along the required url variables like option, view, task, id, etc.

Comment: Dear Sir can you give me any simple code hint or URL where i can get code hints and it process please ?